# Ruby - Extracting my smaller methods out from another method (transforming a string into two numbers and a symbol)

Tags: ruby, string, methods, private, single-responsibility-principle

I have a method (land_connected_rover(coordinates)) that takes a parameter (string that includes two numbers and a letter, space separated) end executes prompts based on this, my problem is that I struggle to extract my assignments from this method, I tried private methods but once I do this, none of my injected classes can reach these variables anymore obvs. I want to have an elegant, SRP based solution, not the current messy one... ew, sorry for hurting your eyes!

'x', 'y' and 'position' variable names are important for other classes as they rely on these prompts...

I want to extract the steps that are assigning x, y and position variable names to the right part of the string.

```
class Controller

  attr_reader :current_rover, :current_surface

  def initialize
    @current_surface = nil
    @current_rover ||= []
  end

  def connect_to_surface(destination)
    @current_surface = destination
  end

  def connect_to_rover(rover)
    @current_rover = rover
  end

  def land_connected_rover(coordinates)
    coordinates = coordinates.delete(' ')
    x = coordinates[0].to_i
    y = coordinates[1].to_i
    position = coordinates[2].to_sym
    self.current_rover.x_coordinates = x
    self.current_rover.y_coordinates = y
    self.current_rover.position = position
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end

  def navigate(command)
    self.current_rover.read_input(command)
  end

  private

  def add_to_grid(x,y)
    @current_surface.record_on_map(x,y)
  end

  def turn_on_rover
    @current_rover.online = true
  end
end
```

I really appreciate the help! And sorry if I asked all the wrong questions, I'm kinda new..

Comment: For landing a rover this isnt that bad :). Probably you can make a move_to(x,y) which sets x y and position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A note about [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost). It's possible to over factor. Worrying about this method probably isn't worth your time. It's an eight line method of simple statements that's easy to understand and it works. Presumably it's tested, but if it isn't, that's something to better spend your time on.

For example, you initialize `@current_rover` to a list, but it's used as a user object. I suspect lots of things will go bang in confusing ways if the user doesn't set `@current_rover`. That would be something to spend time on. You could have tests which try to use a freshly initialized object and ensure they produce meaningful exceptions, or you can side-step all that complexity and decide that it must be initialized with a rover.

Let's treat the refactoring as an exercise.

---

First, let's try to describe all the things that `land_connected_rover` does by commenting each block of things to explain what they do.

```
  def land_connected_rover(coordinates)
    # Parse coordinates.
    coordinates = coordinates.delete(' ')
    x = coordinates[0].to_i
    y = coordinates[1].to_i
    position = coordinates[2].to_sym

    # Set rover coordinates.
    self.current_rover.x_coordinates = x
    self.current_rover.y_coordinates = y
    self.current_rover.position = position

    # Add something to the grid for some reason.
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end
```

Comments like this point at good sheer points for extracting methods. We need something to parse coordinates. Something to set coordinates. And something to add coordinates to the grid. We already have that last one, so extract the other two.

```
    def parse_coordinates(input)
       input = input.delete(' ')

       return {
           x:   coordinates[0].to_i,
           y:   coordinates[1].to_i,
           position: coordinates[2].to_sym
       };
    end

    def set_rover_coordinates(coordinates)
        @current_rover.x_coordinates = coordinates[:x]
        @current_rover.y_coordinates = coordinates[:y]
        @current_rover.position = coordinates[:position]
    end
```

Now these can be documented, reused, and unit tested. Testing may reveal the need to add error handling when the coordinates don't parse, or the `@current_rover` isn't set.

I used `@current_rover` to remain consistent with the rest of the code that uses instance variables for internal access rather than accessors. There are arguments to be made for either way, pick one.

Then put them back together.

```
  def land_connected_rover(input)
    set_rover_coordinates( parse_coordinates(input) )
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end
```

---

From there we can make a few more observations. Why is Controller writing convenience methods to set attributes of Rover? `set_rover_coordinates` should probably move to Rover.

```
  def land_connected_rover(input)
    @current_rover.set_coordinates( parse_coordinates(input) )
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end
```

Who should be parsing coordinates? I can see good reasons for both Rover and Controller needing this. This suggests that you need a Coordinate class.

```
  # In Controller
  def land_connected_rover(input)
    @current_rover.set_coordinates( Coordinate.from_a(input) )
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end

  # In Rover
  def set_coordinates(coordinates)
    @x_coordinates = coordinates.x
    @y_coordinates = coordinates.y
    @position = coordinates.position
  end
```

Now we observe rather than having a rover's coordinates be a bunch of attributes, it should have a single coordinate attribute that takes a Coordinate object.

```
  # In Rover
  attr :coordinates

  # In Controller
  def land_connected_rover(input)
    @current_rover.coordinates( Coordinate.from_a(input) )
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end
```

Now that we have Coordinate objects, Controller can be passed a Coordinate object and not worry about normalizing its input.

```
  def land_connected_rover(coordinates)
    @current_rover.coordinates( coordinates )
    add_to_grid(x,y)
  end
```

Let the caller handle the normalization.

```
  controller.land_connected_rover( Coordinate.from_a([10,20,30] ) )
```

Now that you have Coordinate objects, the caller can use them, and most of the need for conversion will probably go away.

---

From here my next concern is the duplication of coordinates between the Rover and the Surface. The Rover has its own coordinates, and the Surface seems to independently track the Rover's coordinates. I assume both have to remain in sync? If so, that adds complexity and risks bugs. Or maybe the Surface is only tracking where the Rover initially touched down? It's something to consider.

---

Note that most of this was not obvious until I started the refactoring. I'd initially stopped at the first refactoring of `land_connected_rover`, but then thought about it some more, came up with the Coordinate class, and then it cascaded from there. I think the end result is much better, far beyond what I'd expected at the start.

So... yeah, sometimes do worry about the eight line method. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and time you spent with answering, really appreciate it. I ended up with something shorter but my interview was successful so, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

**I ended up with this solution at the end:**

```
class Controller

  attr_reader :current_rover, :current_surface

  def initialize
    @current_surface ||= nil
    @current_rover ||= nil
  end

  def connect_to_surface(destination)
    @current_surface = destination
  end

  def connect_to_rover(rover)
    @current_rover = rover
  end

  def is_mission_ready?
    @current_surface != nil && @current_rover != nil
  end

  def land_connected_rover(coordinates)
    raise 'Mission is not ready to launch yet!' if !is_mission_ready?
    x, y, position = parse_coordinates(coordinates)
    current_rover.x_coordinates = x
    current_rover.y_coordinates = y
    current_rover.position = position
    add_to_grid
  end

  def navigate(command)
    raise 'Navigation is not ready to start yet!' if !is_mission_ready?
    current_rover.read_input(command)
  end

  private

  def parse_coordinates(coordinates)
    fields = coordinates.split(" ")
    [fields[0].to_i, fields[1].to_i, fields[2].to_sym]
  end

  def add_to_grid
    x = current_rover.x_coordinates
    y = current_rover.y_coordinates
    position = current_rover.position
    @current_surface.record_on_map(x,y)
    puts "Rover landed, currently facing: #{current_rover.position}, x-coordinates: #{x}, y-coordinates: #{y}"
    @current_surface.grid
  end
end
```